# How to deal with MFA in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multi-factor-authentication

Since recently I'm requested to MFA azcli login in my pipeline :

> ERROR: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your
> administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use
> multi-factor authentication to access '***************************'.

I'm wondering what approach is recommended to use azcli with MFA through a pipeline.
Is there a way to generate a token to use in his context for instance ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think to fully answer this question we would need more context, like how your azcli command looks like. However, I can still give some general pointers:

In short, you cannot and should not use MFA for automation. MFA is designed to manual work. For cli:s such as the azcli, there is other authentication methods more suitable for automated work.

In this case, you should look into creating a PAT (personal access token) or to use the system access token present in azure devops and authenticate with that token instead. The specific solution depends on the context of what you are doing though, where more information is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I actually use az cli.  
The point was I was using username and passwd to login whereas the trick was to use a service principal. Works now.

Comment: Great to hear that you solved it :)