# How can i login to Azure with MFA using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Currently i login to Azure from Powershell as follows:

```
   az login -u <uname> -p <pwd>
   az account set --subscription <my-subscription>
```

The  never used to have MFA enabled so it was successful. But now MFA is enabled and i get an error:

```
    Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a 
    new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to 
    access
```

Is there anyway that i can automate this in Powershell without having to manually enter in an Authenticator app ?

Comment: You cannot use MFA for automation it is forced to perform Interactive authentication. Check the below answer

Answer (score 2):

Enabled MFA for the user:

[image]

When I tried to login to Azure CLI via non interactive way, I got the same error as below:

```bash
az login -u demouser@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -p ***
```

[image]

The error "***Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to xxx access***" usually occurs if you are trying to authenticate non interactively to the MFA enabled user account.

- You cannot use MFA for automation it is forced to perform Interactive authentication. Refer this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1359461/azure-powershell-mfa) by  *Harpreet Singh Matharoo*.
- If MFA is enabled then you must use interactive flow or service principal authentication.
- Hence make use of **`az login`** command to authenticate interactively.

```bash
az login --tenant TenantID
```

[image]

***Otherwise***, as a **workaround** make use of Service Principal authentication:

```bash
az login --service-principal -u AppID -p ClientSecret --tenant TenantID
```

[image]

**References:**

[How to deal with MFA in azure pipelines - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757942/how-to-deal-with-mfa-in-azure-pipelines) by Bast

[Subsequent az login returns AADSTS50076 for user with MFA · Issue #20771 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20771)